# What's the difference between "itself", "his notion of its self" and "that self" in the sentence below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, ambiguity

> It came to him that he had turned away from the buffalo not because of a womanish nausea at blood and stench and spilling gut; it came to him that he had sickened and turned away because of his shock at seeing the buffalo, a few moments before proud and noble and full of the dignity of life, now stark and helpless, a length of inert meat, divested of **itself**, or **his notion of its self**, swinging grotesquely, mockingly, before him. It was not **itself**; or it was not **that self** that he had imagined it to be. **That self** was murdered; and in that murder he had felt the destruction of something within him, and he had not been able to face it. So he had turned away.

Comment: What does your research say? Try and posit an answer and then ask for confirmation or rebuttal.

Comment: @mohit Thank you for your reply . I wrote my thoughts about these words in other comment , by the way my English is not good so i don't know if i could convey my thoughts or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It was not itself

It was **neither** that creature *that had the character and personality* that he **had seen** a few moments before

> or it was not that self that **he had imagined it to be**

**nor was it** that creature *with that character and personality* that **he had imagined it to be** a few moments before

> That self  was murdered

That creature *with that character and personality* had been murdered.

This is the meaning of "self" as given in the OED as:

> **3b. A person's or thing's individuality or essence at a particular time or in a particular aspect or relation; a person's nature, character, or (occasionally) physical constitution or appearance, considered as different at different times.**
>
> 1910   ‘M. Rutherford’ Pages from Jrnl. (ed. 2) 268   *The self of two hours before seemed to confront him.*
>
> 1975   H. Fleetwood Pict. of Innocence x. 177   *You seem quite like your old self again.*
>
> 2016   Daily Tel. (Nexis) 2 July (Weekend section) 22   *I think my younger self would be astonished by what I went on to achieve.*

Comment: Let's add that the author is milking the word back onto itself for poetic purposes. While very smoothly so, this style is not a model for everyday writing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I agree with the second part of your explanation "nor was it that creature with that character and personality that he had imagined it to be a few moments before" but the first part , i mean this (It was not itself) i think the word itself simply refer to the corpse of buffalo. ( sorry for my poor English)

Comment: @SoGh I don't know whether you have ever seen an animal or human who you knew when it/they was/were alive, but the difference between the living creature and its dead body is quite remarkable. This is the idea of the description. The writer is comparing "selfs".

Comment: @Greybeard     you're kind of right. Maybe i jumped into conclusion too quickly. But i don't see in this context any description of buffalo except that one he had imagined it to be.

Comment: @SoGh This is moving towards philosophy but we may imagine a buffalo - or any other sentient being - as having three "selfs": The character and attributes that you or I think it is (your and my opinion will differ); the character and attributes that the creature thinks it has, and an objective self that is what it really is - it would seem difficult to determine the last. Think of the tale of the three blind men and an elephant.

Answer (score 2):

The term *"self*" [can mean a couple of things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self), such as identity, consciousness, uniqueness or awareness.

The passage quoted seems to describe the loss of this element upon death:

- "*divested of itself*": the loss or deprivation of the buffalo's identity/being/consciousness when it was murdered
- "*his notion of its self*": the man's idea or understanding of the buffalo's identity/being/consciousness
- "*It was not itself*": the corpse was not the same being as the buffalo
- "*not that self that he had imagined it to be*": the corpse was not what the man had previously perceived the buffalo to be.
- "*That self was murdered*": the identity/being/consciousness of the buffalo, which the man had perceived, has been murdered.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and detailed explanation. I somehow agree with you but my guess about those words are these : Here in "divested of itself" i think it refer to that inert meat which is seperated of its skin and in this "his notion of its self" the self here refer to the condition the hanging meat had at that time (swinging grotesquely, mockingly)  and i think two last " self" refer to those mentioned above ( proud and noble and full of the dignity...) and i agree with your explanation about this "It was not itself". ( and sorry for my poor English.)